# Embedding PHP in HTML - failure to populate and display data in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm going through a tutorial on PHP and HTML and the code used in the tutorial doesn't work for me the way it's demonstrated and I'd like to understand why.  I've set up a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/csmart/vkPJf/ so you can see what is happening.  The code is supposed to connect with a database and add and print table data.  It appears that the code is reaching the section that prints a table called Courses and it's failing. It does not appear to be a failure to connect to the database, since I can comment out the failing code and use an insert statement to create a new row of data in the table. Is there a problem with the way the html is embedded in the php and how should the code be corrected?  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
       <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {$("form").validate();});
        </script>
    </head><body>
    <form method="post">
        cid: <input name="cid" class="required digits" maxlength="3" minlength="3"><BR>
        title: <input name="title" class="required" maxlength="200"><BR>
        prof: <input name="prof" maxlength="64"><BR>
        cred: <input name="cred" class="required digits" maxlength="1" minlength="1"><BR>
        cap: <input name="cap" class="required digits" maxlength="2" minlength="2"><BR>
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>

    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $dbhost = 'XXXXXXXX';
    $dbname = 'XXXXXXXX';
    $dbuser = 'XXXXXXXX';
    $dbpass = 'XXXXXXXX';

    $mysql_handle = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbname", "$dbpass", "$dbuser")
    or die("Error connecting to database server");
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $mysql_handle)
    or die("Error selecting database: $dbname ");
    $cid = array_key_exists("cid", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["cid"] : 0;
    $title = array_key_exists("title", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["title"] : '';
    $prof = array_key_exists("prof", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["prof"] : '';
    $cred = array_key_exists("cred", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["cred"] : 0;
    $cap = array_key_exists("cap", $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST["cap"] : 0;

    if($cid <= 0) echo"";
    else if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}$/',$cid)) echo "Invalid cid";
    else if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}$/',$cred)) echo "Invalid cred";
    else if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}$/',$cap)) echo "Invalid cap";
    else if($cid < 0) {
        $rs = mysql_query("select cid from courses where cid = ".$cid);
        if (mysql_numrows($rs) == 0) {
            mysql_query("insert into courses(cid,cap,cred,title,prof) values("
                 . $cid . "," . $cap . "," . $cred
                 . ",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($title) . "'"
                 . ",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($prof) . "')"
                 );
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("update courses set cap=".$cap.", cred=".$cred . ", title='". mysql_real_escape_string($title) . "'" . ", prof='". mysql_real_escape_string($prof) . "'" . " where cid=".$cid
             };
        }
    }

    $rs = mysql_query("select cid,prof,cred,cap,title from courses");
    $nrows=mysql_numrows($rs);

    echo "Courses<table>";
       for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($rs,$i,"cid"))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($rs,$i,"title"))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($rs,$i,"prof"))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($rs,$i,"cred"))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($rs,$i,"cap"))."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo '</table>';
    mysql_close($mysql_handle);
    ?>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: You have parse errors (among other issues). Prep and process your data beforehand, not in the middle of an HTML document.

Comment: look at the colour codeing above.

Comment: Since I didn't author the code, but am trying to learn from what appears to work in the tutorial, can you be more specific?  What is failing to parse?

Comment: The `mysql_query("insert into courses` line is missing a quote somewhere along the way

Comment: Found the extra quotes and deleted them, but I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was hear

```
else if($cid < 0) {
 $rs = mysql_query("select cid from courses where cid = ".$cid);
 if (mysql_numrows($rs) == 0) {
    mysql_query("insert into courses(cid, cap, cred, title, prof) values(" .$cid . "," .$cap . "," .$cred . ",'" . mysql_real_escape_string($title) . "'" .
    ","."'" . mysql_real_escape_string($prof) . "'");
  }
  else {
    mysql_query("update courses set cap=".$cap.", cred=".$cred . ", title='". mysql_real_escape_string($title) ."'" . ", prof='". mysql_real_escape_string($prof) . "'" . " where cid=".$cid);

 }
}
```

attention on **"** and **)** ,**(**